# bounds IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to get my head around scipy.optimize SLSQP functions. Therefore I wrote a simple optimization problem. I just wanted to limit 0<d<10. but I get the error message:tuple index out of range Why can I not limit d? For your help and explanation I would be grateful.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize,Bounds

# bounds = Bounds([0,0], [10, 10])
def objective_fun(d):

    x_theo=d*2+1
    y_theo=-d*2.5+10
    x_m=5
    y_m=5
    objective=(x_m-x_theo)**2+(y_m-y_theo)**2
    return objective

d0=6


res = minimize(objective_fun, d0, method='SLSQP',bounds=Bounds([1],[10]))
```

Comment: your initial guess `d0` must be a tuple, `minimize(objective_fun, (d0,), method='SLSQP',bounds=Bounds([1],[10]))` that must be a tuple note the `(d0,)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. You are right, if I put d0=[6] it works. Thank you